# How do I get around black, square blocks?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

There's a PhD there, tantalizingly close to me, but just out of reach, blocked by those un-explodable blocks. How do I get to it?! (I've also encountered this set-up with another item).

[image: blocked phd]

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to have flight to get that item, unless of course there are specific items that allow their destruction (which is likely).

Comment: In the old version of the game blocks like that were unbreakable and the only way to pass them was flying. No item allowed you to destroy them, but it's probably still to early to rule out the presence of an item in the new versione that can destroy even those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have an item that grants flight.

The list of items which grant permanent flight from the original game is:

- *Lord Of The Pit*
- *Transcendence*
- *A Pony / White Pony*
- *Holy Grail*
- *Fate*
- *Spirit Of The Night*
- *Dead Dove*
- *Guppy* or *Lord of Flies* (collecting 3 *Guppy* items or 3 "flies" items in one
  playthrough will give Isaac permanent flight)
- *The Hanged Man* (Tarot Card)

There are probably several more in Rebirth.

Comment: The Hanged Man tarot card can also be used to get flight for a single room.

Comment: you can also use the jump manual to jump into such spaces, but it is annoyingly imprecise.

Answer (score 2):

You can also clip through the blocks with two bombs.